# Normal subgroup is permutable!

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Where can I find the proof of : The normal subgroups are always permutable??
The group is permutable if $HX=XH$ for every subgroup $X$ of group $G$( $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$).

Comment: Can this property  be extended to the semigroups as well?

Comment: $hx=x(x^{-1}hx)$ and $x^{-1}hx\in H$ since $H$ is normal so $HX\subset XH$ the same idea shows $XH\subset HX$.

Comment: Isn't this basically the definition of a normal subgroup?

Comment: Yes it's basically the definition of a normal subgroup, but I am also interested to find out whether this property can be extended in the class of semigroups??

Comment: So if we have a normal sub-semigroup $X $ of a permutable semigroup$Y$, is $X$ a permutable semigroup?

Comment: The title is making me hum Camelot.  ("Per-mu-TAB-le.")

Comment: See GroupProps for [one definition of normal subsemigroup](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subsemigroup) and weaker variants.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then $xH=Hx$ for any element $x\in G$, so $XH=HX$ for any subset $X$ of $G$ (and the subgroups $X$ of $G$ in particular).

If by "normal subsemigroup" we mean that $N$ is a subsemigroup of (semigroup) $G$ such that:

$$ Ng = gN \; \forall g\in G $$

then the same sort of proof shows $NX = XN$ for any subset $X$ of $G$.